# Symfony3 FSOUserbundle and FR3LdapBundle configuration

Tags: php, ldap, symfony

working on a Symfony3 project and trying to use this two bundles in conjunction authenticate a user agains Directory service through LDAP :

```
FR3DLdapBundle
FOSUserBundle
```

I have followed the docs to config these FSOUserBundel works fine on ints own, its when i added FR3DLdapBundle according to its [Docks](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and am left with this error:

```
    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to FR3D\LdapBundle\Driver\ZendLdapDriver::__construct() must be an instance of 
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface, instance of
 Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger given, called in /Users/tomasz.koprowski/Dev/cambio-
    back_end/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1729 and defined
```

ps. I did clear my cache.

now the file where i think i might have a mistake is security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    # Preserve plain text password in token for refresh the user.
    # Analyze the security considerations before turn off this setting.
    erase_credentials: false

    encoders:
        AcmeBundle\Acme\User\LdapUser: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]

        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    #    providers:
    #        in_memory:
    #            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
#        dev:
#            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
#            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fr3d_ldap: ~
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /profile
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

            #        main:
            #            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

and config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Cambio\CambioBundle\Entity\User

fr3d_ldap:
fr3d_ldap:
    driver:
        host:                your.host.foo
#       port:                389    # Optional
#       username:            foo    # Optional
#       password:            bar    # Optional
#       bindRequiresDn:      true   # Optional
#       baseDn:              ou=users, dc=host, dc=foo   # Optional
#       accountFilterFormat: (&(uid=%s)) # Optional. sprintf format %s will be the username
#       optReferrals:        false  # Optional
#       useSsl:              true   # Enable SSL negotiation. Optional
#       useStartTls:         true   # Enable TLS negotiation. Optional
#       accountCanonicalForm: 3 # ACCTNAME_FORM_BACKSLASH this is only needed if your users have to login with something like HOST\User
#       accountDomainName: HOST
#       accountDomainNameShort: HOST # if you use the Backslash form set both to Hostname than the Username will be converted to HOST\User
    user:
        baseDn: ou=users, dc=host, dc=foo
        filter: (&(ObjectClass=Person))
#       usernameAttribute: uid # Optional
        attributes:          # Specify ldap attributes mapping [ldap attribute, user object method]
#           - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername } # Default
#           - { ldap_attr: cn,   user_method: setName }     # Optional

#           - { ldap_attr: ...,  user_method: ... }         # Optional
#   service:
#       user_hydrator: fr3d_ldap.user_hydrator.default # Overrides default user hydrator
#       ldap_manager: fr3d_ldap.ldap_manager.default   # Overrides default ldap manager

    user:
      - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername }
      - { ldap_attr: mail, user_method: setEmail }
```

Any idea guys? thank

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because FR3DLdapBundle does not fully support Symfony3. earlier in 2.8 version class Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger implemented Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface that extended Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, in Symfony 3 class implements only Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface that does not extend anything, it's just an interface. And in FR3DLdapBundle class FR3D\LdapBundle\Driver\ZendLdapDriver expects as second argument Psr\Log\LoggerInterface. That's all.

You can write this as issue on their [github page](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle)

Or you can fork their repo, fix expected argument [here](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/master/Driver/ZendLdapDriver.php) and make pull request. at the meantime work with your bundle, then change it back to theirs when they accept and merge your pull request

Answer (score 0):

why don't you read through my blog [Symfony AD Integration](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/).

I see in your "config.yml" file, you've got "fr3d_ldap:" twice. That could be a problem...

I suggest using the LDAP test server I show in the blog to verify things work first, then you can move on to your own AD server.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is still attempting to upgrade from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 and encountering issues with the FR3DLdapBundle as seen in the original post:

1) Upgrade FR3DLdapBundle from v2.0 to v3.0 using composer

This should remove the bug that is being seen by the original poster in their question above.

2) In your Symfony app/config.yml, under the settings for the FR3DLdapBundle, add the "usernameAttribute" setting under the "user" section, and set it to "sAMAccountName"

Example:

```
fr3d_ldap:
 driver:
   host:     XX.XX.XX.XX
   username: user@domain.com
   password: password
   accountDomainName: domain.com
   accountDomainNameShort: DOMA
 user:
    baseDn: Ou=ListingUsers,DC=domain,DC=com
    usernameAttribute: sAMAccountName
    filter: (&(ObjectClass=Person))
    attributes:
        - { ldap_attr: samaccountname,  user_method: setUsername }
```

If you had been using an older version of the bundle, you probably didn't have this in your configuration, and you will need it to make it work.  I found this solution here: https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/issues/131

These two changes together solved my issues and made it possible for me to use FR3DLdapBundle on Symfony 3.4